# Convergence Question related to $e^x$

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence, power-series

[image]

This is an IB question about power series and convergence. I have no idea how to even approach this question.

For 3a) I have figured out up to using the power series equation
$$
f(x) = (1 + ax)(1 + bx) = (1 + ax)(1 − bx + \ldots (−1)^n \cdot b^nx^n +\ldots)
$$
Now I have no idea how this can be turned to: $c_n = (−b)^{n-1}\cdot(a-b)$

Also for 3b) What is it even asking? Where did the $e^x$ come from? And what $x^2$?

Please help!!

Thank you

Comment: They are asking you to match $e^x=1+x+\frac{x^2}2+\frac{x^3}{3!}+\cdots$ up to the quadratic term.

Comment: I see I see thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\begin{align}
f(x) &= (1 + ax)(1 + bx) \\
&= (1 + ax)(1 − bx + \ldots +(−1)^n\cdot b^n\cdot x^n + \ldots)\\
&= (1)(1 − bx + \ldots+(−1)^n\cdot b^n\cdot x^n + \ldots) \\
&+ (ax)(1 − bx + \ldots+(−1)^n\cdot b^n\cdot x^n + \ldots)\\
&= 1 − bx + \ldots+(−1)^n\cdot b^n\cdot x^n + \ldots \\
&+ (ax − abx^2 + ...+(−1)^n \cdot a \cdot b^n\cdot x^{n+1} + ...)
\end{align}
Now notice that the terms involving $x^{n+1}$ are

1. $(-1)^{n+1} b^{n+1} x^{n+1} = (-1)(-1)^{n} b \cdot  b^{n} x^{n+1}$, and
2. $(−1)^n \cdot a \cdot b^n\cdot x^{n+1}$

Summing gets us

\begin{align}
S 
&= (-1)(-1)^{n} b \cdot  b^{n} x^{n+1} + (−1)^n \cdot a \cdot b^n\cdot x^{n+1} \\
&= (-1)^n x^{n+1} b^n\left( (-1) b +  \cdot a  \right) \\
&= (-1)^n x^{n+1} b^n\left( a-b \right) \\
&= (-1)^n x^{n+1} b^n\left( a-b \right)
\end{align}
So the coefficient of $x^n$ (one term before $S$, hence involving one more $-$ sign) is 
$$
(-1)^{n-1} b^{n-1} (a - b) = (-b)^{n-1} (a-b). 
$$

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH!